# Why is $\hom(G \times H, A) \cong \hom(G,A) \times \hom(H,A)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Let $A$ be abelian group and $G$ and $H$ be groups. Why does the following hold?

$$\hom(G \times H, A) \cong \hom(G,A) \times \hom(H,A)$$

I tried my best and couldn't come up with an isomorphism. Any help?

This claim has been made [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/661742/360858).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be a homomorphism from $G \times H$ to $A$.  Then you get a homomorphism from $G$ to $A$ by sending $g$ to $\phi(g,1_H)$.  You also get another homomorphism from $H$ to $A$ by sending $h$ to $\phi (1_G,h)$.   Thus given the homomorphism $\phi$, you get a pair of homomorphisms, one from $G$ to $A$, and another from $H$ to $A$.  This is your function $$\textrm{hom}(G\times H, A) \rightarrow \textrm{hom}(G,A) \times \textrm{hom}(H,A)$$ which you need to show is a bijection.

Comment: So there is only bijection, not an isomorphism? What I need is an isomorphism. If I assume $G$ and $H$ to be abelian, do I get an isomorphism?

Comment: Check it yourself: is that map a homomorphism?

Comment: Looks like it is. Isn't it? (feels awkward)

Comment: I don't know, but probably (awkwardness intensifies)

Answer (score 4):

Consider$$\begin{array}{rccc}\Phi\colon&\hom(G\times H,A)&\longrightarrow&\hom(G,A)\times\hom(H,A)\\&\varphi&\mapsto&\left(\left(\begin{array}{ccc}G&\longrightarrow&A\\g&\mapsto&\varphi(g,e)\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ccc}H&\longrightarrow&A\\h&\mapsto&\varphi(e,h)\end{array}\right)\right).\end{array}$$